# CSS - Footer image not resizing correctly when browser viewport changes

Tags: css

I have an MVC app with an image in the footer. My CSS currently looks as follows:

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-150px; /* This puts the footer 100px below the bottom of the page*/
    width:70%;
    height: 170px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background-image: url("/Images/Footer/Footer3.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

The problem I have is that the image is not being resized correctly to fit within the width and height of the container. Parts of the image are cut off. And when I resize the browser viewport (shrink it), more of the image is cut off. The image size is 1000x175 if that helps. I would like the image to be responsive and be auto resized correctly within the container.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try

```
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Not until just now. That seems to work, but I lost my centering which I wanted.

Comment: the background image should span all over the DIV width... what do you mean with "centering"?

Comment: Instead of the image being left justified or right justified, I want it centered along the bottom.